# In javascript jquery html table is not displayed when appended through js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending data in table body through js but when calling the `getInvManhistory()` method in `docment.ready()` it shows the table with appended data but when I call it `onClick` of search button it shows blank table. I debugged the code the data is appended at beginning but it get blank at the end.

Advance thanks. Please help.

```js
var invsorno = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  // getInvManhistory(); When calling here the table gets displayed.

  $("#search").click(function() {
    alert("searchs");
    getInvManhistory(); //when calliung with search button table is shown empty
  });
  // get_workflow_history();
});

function getInvManhistory() {
  var tablebody = "";
  invsorno = $("#invSrNo").val(),
    $.cordys.ajax({
      method: 'SearchInvManDetails',
      parameters: {
        invseqno: invsorno,
        invtype: "",
        FromDate: "",
        ToDate: "",
      },
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      namespace: 'http://schemas.cordys.com/IM_DBMetaData',
      success: function(response) {
        if ($.isArray(response.tuple)) {
          var workflow_len = response.tuple.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < workflow_len; i++) {
            tablebody += "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_SEQ_NO + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_INITIATOR_ID + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.DEPARTMENT + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_ROLE + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.SOURCE_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.TARGET_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.STATUS + "</td>" +
              "</tr>";
          }
        } else if ($.isEmptyObject(response.tuple)) {
          tablebody += "<tr align='center'>" +
            "<td colspan='6' style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Data Not Found</td>" +
            "</tr>";
        } else {
          tablebody += "<tr>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_SEQ_NO + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_INITIATOR_ID + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.DEPARTMENT + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_ROLE + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.SOURCE_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.TARGET_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.STATUS + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";
        }
        $('#searchdetails tbody').html("");
        $('#searchdetails tbody').append(tablebody);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

  <link href="../JavaSources_CustomLibrary/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/base/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../JavaSources_CustomLibrary/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="../JavaSources_CustomLibrary/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/cordys/thirdparty/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/cordys/html5/cordys.html5sdk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src='../IM_JSFiles/IM_Search.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <title>Search</title>
</head>

<style>
  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div style="width: 60%; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; background-color: gainsboro;">

    <div>
      <h3 style="background-color: red;text-align: left;color: #FFF;padding: 5px;">Investment Management Search Screen</h3>
      <div style="width: 60%;border: 1px solid gray;margin:0;overflow: hidden;padding: 5px;">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0px;">
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
              <label for="invSrNo" style="width: 125px;">Inv Sr. No:</label>
              <input id="invSrNo" name="imInvSrNo" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
              <label for="investmentType" style="width: 125px;">Investment Type:</label>
              <input id="investmentType" name="imInvestmentType" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0px;">
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
              <label for="fromDate" style="width: 125px;">From Date:</label>
              <input id="fromDate" name="imFromDate" type="date">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
              <label for="toDate" style="width: 125px;">To Date:</label>
              <input id="toDate" name="imToDate" type="date">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0px;">

            <div class="form-group" style="float: right;margin-right: 42px;">

              <button id="search" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Search</button>
              <button id="view" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">View</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid gray;margin:0;overflow: hidden;padding: 5px;">
        <table style="width: 100%" id="searchdetails">

          <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: red; color: #FFF;">
              <th>Inv Sr.No</th>
              <th>Initiator Name</th>
              <th>Department</th>
              <th>Role</th>
              <th>Source WBC Code</th>
              <th>Target WBC Code</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody></tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If default type of button element is `submit` then you should try with `type="button"`, I think.

Comment: Have you stepped though in the browser? What did you see?

Comment: When I click on search the table gets generated but after  $('#searchdetails tbody').html("");
        $('#searchdetails tbody').append(tablebody);
It automatically gets blank

Comment: Why not just `$('#searchdetails tbody').html(tablebody)` ?

Comment: It creates the table while debugging till 
$('#searchdetails tbody').html(tablebody);
after this table gets blank

Comment: "<tr><td>INV_17_CBC_00062</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>null</td></tr><tr><td>INV_17_CBC_00059</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>null</td></tr><tr><td>INV_17_CBC_00052</td><td>test update</td><td>test update</td><td>test update</td><td>test update</td><td>test update</td><td>Completed</td></tr><tr><td>INV_17_CBC_00051</td><td>dileep</td><td>test NB</td><td>test NB</td><td>test NB</td><td>test NB</td><td>null</td></tr>"

Comment: Please read this [mcve].  Can you recreate the issue, eg without the ajax call?  Here's a version of it working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/mgmeu30f/

Comment: Actually I am very new so kindly help me..It works fine when the method is called from document.ready();
but dont know why its not showing data in table.The above data is shown while debugging but after the
$('#searchdetails tbody').append(tablebody);
the tablebody gets reset

Comment: @freedomn-m I just noticed that my html page is getting reloaded after 
$('#searchdetails tbody').append(tablebody); how to stop it from reloading

Comment: There's either some other code causing the issue or there's a problem with your selector/ID matching in your code that isn't the same as the question's code.   Have a look at [mcve] and see if you can recreate the issue either here in a codeblock or on jsfiddle/codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are using jquery selector $ but not referencing jquery in your code so I just add jquery reference in code like.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the complete working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<style>
th,
  td {
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
  var invsorno = "";
 $(document).ready(function() {
 // getInvManhistory(); When calling here the table gets displayed.

$("#search").click(function() {
 alert("searchs");
getInvManhistory(); //when calliung with search button table is shown empty
 });
          // get_workflow_history();
   });

  function getInvManhistory() {
 var tablebody = "";
 invsorno = $("#invSrNo").val(),
  $.cordys.ajax({
  method: 'SearchInvManDetails',
  parameters: {
    invseqno: invsorno,
    invtype: "",
    FromDate: "",
    ToDate: "",
  },
  async: false,


cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  namespace: 'http://schemas.cordys.com/IM_DBMetaData',
  success: function(response) {
    if ($.isArray(response.tuple)) {
      var workflow_len = response.tuple.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < workflow_len; i++) {
        tablebody += "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_SEQ_NO + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_INITIATOR_ID + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.DEPARTMENT + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_ROLE + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.SOURCE_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.TARGET_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + response.tuple[i].old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.STATUS + "</td>" +
          "</tr>";
      }
    } else if ($.isEmptyObject(response.tuple)) {
      tablebody += "<tr align='center'>" +
        "<td colspan='6' style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Data Not Found</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    } else {
      tablebody += "<tr>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_SEQ_NO + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_INITIATOR_ID + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.DEPARTMENT + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.IM_ROLE + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.SOURCE_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.TARGET_WBC_CODE + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + response.tuple.old.INVESTMENTMANAGEMENT_DETAILS.STATUS + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    }
    $('#searchdetails tbody').html("");
    $('#searchdetails tbody').append(tablebody);
  }
});
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>   <div style="width: 60%; border: 1px solid gray; margin: 0 auto; overflow:    hidden; background-color: gainsboro;">

<div>
  <h3 style="background-color: red;text-align: left;color: #FFF;padding: 5px;">Investment Management Search Screen</h3>
  <div style="width: 60%;border: 1px solid gray;margin:0;overflow: hidden;padding: 5px;">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
          <label for="invSrNo" style="width: 125px;">Inv Sr. No:</label>
          <input id="invSrNo" name="imInvSrNo" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
          <label for="investmentType" style="width: 125px;">Investment Type:</label>
          <input id="investmentType" name="imInvestmentType" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0px;">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
          <label for="fromDate" style="width: 125px;">From Date:</label>
          <input id="fromDate" name="imFromDate" type="date">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 48%;">
          <label for="toDate" style="width: 125px;">To Date:</label>
          <input id="toDate" name="imToDate" type="date">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 100%; padding: 10px 0px;">

        <div class="form-group" style="float: right;margin-right: 42px;">

          <button id="search" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Search</button>
          <button id="view" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">View</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid gray;margin:0;overflow: hidden;padding: 5px;">
    <table style="width: 100%" id="searchdetails">

      <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: red; color: #FFF;">
          <th>Inv Sr.No</th>
          <th>Initiator Name</th>
          <th>Department</th>
          <th>Role</th>
          <th>Source WBC Code</th>
          <th>Target WBC Code</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Screen Shot:
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: That's pretty cool, but the answer would benefit from a little explanation - what was the error? What did you change? Perhaps just show the bits that you fixed, rather than the complete code

Comment: Problem was that He was not referencing jquery but using $ in his code.

Comment: I tried with jquery.min.js but its not the solution..I just noticed that my html page is getting reloaded after $('#searchdetails tbody').append(tablebody); how to stop it from reloading

Comment: @freedomn-m I also tried that but things did'nt work.The page still gets reloaded

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand what you want to acheive? the page reload when? I have tried your code after editing there is no reloading of page.

Comment: @TAHATEMURII The page is reloading after we click on search It generates the table by th use of response.
Then after appending the table.When the ajax call is complete and the method is completed it again goes to doument.ready();it reloads the page.How to avoid that??

Comment: Please try assign your ajax call to variable then call abort(); method to cancel call like   var x=  $.cordys.ajax({
    //your ajax code here
});
x.abort();

Comment: can u provide me some example coz I tried with assigning the method to var but It is not working.